# Pyalgotrade's ninjatraderfeed fails after 7 onBars() calls

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, pyalgotrade, back-testing

I'm trying to use the [ninjaTrader](http://gbeced.github.io/pyalgotrade/docs/v0.18/html/barfeed.html#module-pyalgotrade.barfeed.ninjatraderfeed) feed via CSV files containing minute data. 
The program works as intended for seven onBars calls, then spits an error:

> self.info(str(instr) + " current Open price: %.2f" %
>   (bars.getBar(instr).getOpen())) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has
>   no attribute 'getOpen'

My code:

```
class myExample(strategy.BacktestingStrategy):
    def __init__(self, feed, instruments):
        self.__position = None
        strategy.BacktestingStrategy.__init__(self, feed, 10000)
        self.__instruments = instruments


    def onBars(self, bars):
        for instr in self.__instruments:
            self.info(str(instr) + " current Open price: %.2f" % (bars.getBar(instr).getOpen()))

feed = ninjatraderfeed.Feed(Frequency.MINUTE)
feed.addBarsFromCSV("AMZN",  "AMZN.csv")
feed.addBarsFromCSV("MMM",  "MMM.csv")
strat = myExample(feed, ["AMZN","MMM"])
strat.run()
```

AMZN.csv

```
20161227 093100 761.8262    763.77  761.58  763.4   11629
20161227 093200 762.12  762.48  761.2   761.85  15101
20161227 093300 762.215 762.769 761.77  761.77  13181
20161227 093400 762.3516    762.62  762.066 762.2211    6483
20161227 093500 762.73  762.88  762.2   762.392 8093
20161227 093600 763.055 763.36  762.7318    762.7318    11446
20161227 093700 762.45  763.4595    762.45  763.17  8561
20161227 093800 762.8   763 762.45  762.75  10116
```

MMM.csv

```
20161227 093100 178.95  178.95  178.775 178.775 200
20161227 093200 178.58  178.75  178.57  178.73  15968
20161227 093300 178.9   178.935 178.765 178.765 604
20161227 093400 179.12  179.14  178.91  178.91  2517
20161227 093500 178.8167    179.15  178.8167    179.12  4236
20161227 093600 178.74  178.92  178.74  178.918 2900
20161227 093800 178.78  178.78  178.78  178.78  100
20161227 093900 178.95  178.99  178.9   178.9   1300
```

Output:

```
2016-12-27 09:31:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] AMZN current Open price: 761.83
2016-12-27 09:31:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] MMM current Open price: 178.95
2016-12-27 09:32:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] AMZN current Open price: 762.12
2016-12-27 09:32:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] MMM current Open price: 178.58
2016-12-27 09:33:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] AMZN current Open price: 762.22
2016-12-27 09:33:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] MMM current Open price: 178.90
2016-12-27 09:34:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] AMZN current Open price: 762.35
2016-12-27 09:34:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] MMM current Open price: 179.12
2016-12-27 09:35:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] AMZN current Open price: 762.73
2016-12-27 09:35:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] MMM current Open price: 178.82
2016-12-27 09:36:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] AMZN current Open price: 763.05
2016-12-27 09:36:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] MMM current Open price: 178.74
2016-12-27 09:37:00+00:00 strategy [INFO] AMZN current Open price: 762.45
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 43, in <module>
    strat.run()
  File "/home/work/pyCharmZipEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyalgotrade/strategy/__init__.py", line 512, in run
    self.__dispatcher.run()
  File "/home/work/pyCharmZipEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyalgotrade/dispatcher.py", line 109, in run
    eof, eventsDispatched = self.__dispatch()
  File "/home/work/pyCharmZipEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyalgotrade/dispatcher.py", line 97, in __dispatch
    if self.__dispatchSubject(subject, smallestDateTime):
  File "/home/work/pyCharmZipEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyalgotrade/dispatcher.py", line 75, in __dispatchSubject
    ret = subject.dispatch() is True
  File "/home/work/pyCharmZipEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyalgotrade/feed/__init__.py", line 108, in dispatch
    self.__event.emit(dateTime, values)
  File "/home/work/pyCharmZipEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyalgotrade/observer.py", line 61, in emit
    handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/work/pyCharmZipEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyalgotrade/strategy/__init__.py", line 505, in __onBars
    self.onBars(bars)
  File "example.py", line 30, in onBars
    self.info(str(instr) + " current Open price: %.2f" % (bars.getBar(instr).getOpen()))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getOpen
```

The only thing I changed in ninjatraderfeed.py was getDelimiter() to use "," instead of ";"

Why would it stop working after seven onBars calls?

EDIT: Copied first 8 values from each csv file.

Answer (score 0):

At "20161227 093700", there is only AMZN minute data. `bars.getBar('MMM')` returns `None`, it throws `AttributeError` when you try accessing `getOpen` from `None`.

You can check existence before using specific bar.

```
if bars.getBar(instr):
    self.info(str(instr) + " current Open price: %.2f" % (bars.getBar(instr).getOpen()))
```